# SuSE: LD_LIBRARY_PATH not overriding /lib64/

Tags: shared-libraries, glibc, suse

how may i have my local glibc used instead of the root lib64 glibc? I've obtained a newer version of glibc and extracted to a local directory with ld_library_path written to point to that local path, but the application is still looking at the library in /lib64/.
How do I override this?

> gate
>   gate: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by  /p/work/aapplasa/gate/usr/lib64/libproxy.so.1)
>
> ldd --version
>   ldd (GNU libc) 2.11.3
>
> rpm2cpio rpm/glibc-2.19-16.2.5.x86_64.rpm | cpio -idmv
>   setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /p/work/aapplasa/gate/usr/lib64
>
> gate
>   gate: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by  /p/work/aapplasa/gate/usr/lib64/libproxy.so.1)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple glibc libraries on a single host](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/847179/multiple-glibc-libraries-on-a-single-host)

Comment: I am not building an executable, instead i am merely executing one. How can I get it to refer to the glibc directory i have in my local area? I believe the dependencies of glibc is accounted for in the same local area.

Comment: Your belief is not correct. Please read the above answer, and pay particular attention to the `ld-linux` part of it. If you can't rebuild the binary, you'll have to binary-patch it, or use chroot (as I also explained in the linked answer).